# Casting Buttons, TextViews, editText,etc

Tags: android, view

For example,

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById (R.id...) 
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById (R.id..)
```

Why do we do this? When do we have to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to do explicit casting whenever we cast object of some class to its subclass.

findViewById returns object of View class, and to get an object of Button, EditText, etc, from this object we need to do explicit cast.

We need to do explicit casting when we need to access methods and fields defined into subclasses, like `setText()`.

We dont need to explicit cast View, when we need to access only View class's methods, like:

`setOnClickListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is used when you want to use component defined in the xml.

When you define textview or any component in xml one Integer hash code is defined for it in r.java.

So when you want to use it as a text view you have to cast it in textview.

Hope it help!!